# new SQAUSH FS drives are autocreted in Deepin 20 operating system. How to remove

Tags: deepin, squashfs

I am new to Linux world. I recently installed Deepin 20 Linux distribution in my Lenovo C940. After few days this strange partition appeared automatically.

- What are these drives?
- Do I really need them?
- How to remove them?

These appeared after I [installed flutter using snap](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux).

When I open the terminal inside these partitions, I am getting the below names:

```
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/snap/core18/1932
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/snap/flutter-gallery/22
/snap/flutter/31
```

[image: new drive]

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue, Its the snap app which has caused the virtual disk mounted to the system.

I followed the steps mentioned in the below link.

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-completely-remove-snap/19395/2

Namely:

1. Find installed snaps: `snap list`
2. Remove installed snaps: `sudo snap remove <package>`
3. Remove snapd: `sudo apt purge snapd`
4. Remove snap directory from home: `rm -rf ~/snap`
5. If you receive an error removing snapd then do the following: `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd` then run: `sudo apt purge snapd`

... and then rebooted the computer. Everything came back to normal.

It also uninstalled flutter as well. I will use the alternate option to install flutter.